MODIS burned area summary across years: correct for consecutive year burning (Dec 31 to Jan 01 fires)
I want to calculate the number of times pixels were burned within a 20-year-period using the MODIS burned area product.
On Google EarthEngine, I exported annual summaries from the MODIS/061/MCD64A1 collection (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/MODIS_061_MCD64A1). The collection contains monthly burned area with day of year of the fire, as well as day of year for earliest and latest detected change. It seems the latter two variables do  not necessarily encode fire, but only if the BurnDate variable does not equal zero, the detected change was attributed to fire.
From the described collection, I summarised by calculating

A boolean indicating whether there was some non-zero BurnDate found across the monthly layers
An integer providing the minimum day-of-year for FirstDay
An integer providing the maximum day-of-year for LastDay
An integer providing the minimum day-of-year for BurnDate
An integer providing the maximum day-of-year for BurnDate

Now, I want to count the number of years in which a pxiel was marked "burned". However, I am not sure what variables I can use to make sure there are no pixels where the same fire was detected at the end of a year and the beginning of the subsequent year. The minimum and maximum values for FirstDay and LastDay seem to peak really in at the beginning or the end of each year of the exported tiles.
How can I get the correct number of fires per pixel over the time period? Does anyone have experience and knows about solutions and potential pitfalls? (Ideally, the approach would be computationally efficient.)

Have you considered using fire season (which depends where you are) rather than calendar year?

@user2856 My data set is global, so I would like some generally applicable approach without a priori knowledge. Also, it should be computationally manageable... Of course, if there is no other option, I could split the map into regions and figure out when they usually burn...
